# Differential equation confusion about $y$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say I have the ODE: $\frac{dy}{dt}(y + t) - b(t) = 0$, for some continuous $b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that it's not exact, but I am confused about $y$.

Let $N = (y + t)$ and $M = -b(t)$, then $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = 1$?

If I understand ODE's correctly, the $y$ in $N = (y + t)$ is supposed to be a function of $t$?

But then $\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial t} = \text{"something"} + 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}(y + t) - b(t) = 0$$
$$(y + t)dy - b(t)dt = 0$$
$$Mdy+Ndt=0$$
You need for exactness:
$$\dfrac {\partial M}{\partial t}=\dfrac {\partial N}{\partial y}$$
$$\partial_t(y+t)=\partial_y(-b(t))$$
Which is false. Since you have that:

$$\partial_t(y+t)=1$$

You consider $y+t$ as if $y$ is constant and $t$ the variable since you take partial derivative with respect to $t$
$$\partial_y(-b(t))=0$$
It's not exact since:
$$1 \ne 0$$

---

Note that:
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial t} = \text{"something"} + 1$$
The something is just zero since $y$ is cvonsidered as a constant.

*If I understand ODE's correctly, the y in N=(y+t) is supposed to be a function of t?*

$y(t)$ is a function of $t$ but with partial derivative it is considered as a constant.